# Как задать число из инпута в аргумент функции?

Tags: javascript, dom

Надо как-то решить проблему передачу значении из инпутов `inputCharCode1` и `inputCharCode2` в аргументы в этой строке `String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(inputCharCode1, inputCharCode2));`

Не понимаю как это работает и как задать значение.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
var inputLength = document.querySelector('.inputLength');
var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let arr = [];
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inputCharCode1 = document.querySelector('.inputCharCode1');
  var inputCharCode2 = document.querySelector('.inputCharCode2');
  arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (Number(inputLength.value)); i++) {
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(inputCharCode2, inputCharCode1));
  }
  console.log(arr);
  input.value = arr.join('');
});

function getRandomIntInclusive(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text">
<br><br>
<label for="inputLength">String Length: <input class="inputLength" name="inputLength" type="text"></label>
<br><br>
<label for="inputCharCode1">From: <input type="text" name="inputCharCode1" class="inputCharCode1"></label>
<label for="inputCharCode2">To: <input type="text" name="inputCharCode2" class="inputCharCode2"></label>
<br><br>
<button class="button">Запустить</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает HTMLElement, а функция `getRandomIntInclusive` принимает два числа.

В строке

```
arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(inputCharCode2, inputCharCode1));
```

В функцию вместо чисел передаются элементы. Так как получаемые элементы - input, можно получить введенное значение с помощью свойства `value`.

```
arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(inputCharCode2.value, inputCharCode1.value));
```

В некоторых случаях этого достаточно, так как внутри функций могут использоваться операторы, которые сами приводят свои операнды к числу, однако в данном случае, перед передачей в функцию лучше привести аргументы к числу.

Например с помощью функции `Number`

```
arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(Number(inputCharCode2.value), Number(inputCharCode1.value)));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Решил задачу. Причина в моей невнимательности!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
var inputLength = document.querySelector('.inputLength');
var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let arr = [];
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var inputCharCode1 = document.querySelector('.inputCharCode1').value;
  var inputCharCode2 = document.querySelector('.inputCharCode2').value;
  arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (Number(inputLength.value)); i++) {
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(getRandomIntInclusive(+inputCharCode2, +inputCharCode1));
  }
  console.log(arr);
  input.value = arr.join('');
});

function getRandomIntInclusive(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text">
<br><br>
<label for="inputLength">String Length: <input class="inputLength" name="inputLength" type="text"></label>
<br><br>
<label for="inputCharCode1">From: <input type="text" name="inputCharCode1" class="inputCharCode1"></label>
<label for="inputCharCode2">To: <input type="text" name="inputCharCode2" class="inputCharCode2"></label>
<br><br>
<button class="button">Запустить</button>
```

Comment: Блин, второй раз мне стыдно! Мне надо работать над внимательностью! Спасибо тебе @meine)

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев, не за что) слева сверху галочка для принятия ответа, если он Вам помог!